# Multiple Hosts connection in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am able to connect to multiple org in single host using this link https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org

For connecting multiple org using multiple host i followed the below link:
https://medium.com/1950labs/publish-a-business-network-in-multi-host-hyperledger-fabric-a5ad2015a487

While starting the business network i'm getting this error

> Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error:
>   Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message:  is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)
>   Command failed

I tried checking the docker container logs I got some error as:

> 2018-11-23 06:41:47.029 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 043 [mychannel][2a3a414e] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid: 2a3a414e85ab4e1ff0b7b2587147bb496e8586a6475685f6777bc1cd5f89f1a0**

How can I resolve the problem? Any suggestions?

-TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `Error: 2 UNKNOWN: chaincode error (status: 500, message: is not a valid endorsement system chaincode)`
Means that you are trying to use composer 0.20 against a fabric 1.1 network. Composer 0.20 only works with a Fabric 1.2, 1.3 network, Composer 0.19 only works with a fabric 1.1 network. So either you need to change to the correct version of composer for your fabric network, or you need to change the version of your fabric network to match the version of composer you are using.